# File Uploading in jsp

Tags: jsp

There is an issue  in the file uploading part.

Here is the code

```
<form action="uploadlogoc.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="center">
<tr><td>
USER:</td><td><select name="userDetails">
<%
while(rs.next()){%>
<option><%=rs.getString("username") %></option>
<%} %>
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject</td><td><input type="text" name="subject"/></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>File:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" size="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="s1" value="Uploadfile"><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

Values in the subject field and username field shouldn't be passed to next page, because of the presence of enctype. When we remove it value will pass,but file is not uploaded. What is the reason?

```
Connection cone=null;
Statement smt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
DbConnection con=new DbConnection();
try{
cone=con.Connection();
String sql="SELECT * FROM reg";
smt=cone.createStatement();
rs=smt.executeQuery(sql);
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Comment: No notification of errors

Comment: can you show us uploadlogoc.jsp relevant code

Comment: uploadlogoc.jsp code?

Comment: Connection cone=null;
    Statement smt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    DbConnection con=new DbConnection();
    try{
    cone=con.Connection();
    String sql="SELECT * FROM reg";
    smt=cone.createStatement();
    rs=smt.executeQuery(sql);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70951/file-uploading-in-jsp can u paste the code here

Comment: Can you paste it in question rather than pasting in as comment?

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file,we must use enctype="multipart/form-data"
but if use this along with some text fields,parsing of these fields(request.getParameter) returns null
So we have to follow another procedure
We will use form.jsp,upload.java,display.jsp

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name:<input type="text" name="text">
<br>
Select File to Upload:<input type="file" name="fileName">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
package helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class upload
 */
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,    // 10 MB 
maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,       // 50 MB
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)       // 100 MB
public class upload extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "new";
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public upload() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // gets absolute path of the web application
    String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
 // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String uploadFilePath = applicationPath + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;
    //Declare fields for storing parse values from user
    String name="";
    //url which you will store in database
    String url="";
 // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
    }

    //Contains fileName
    String fileName = null;


    int i=0;
    //Get all the parts from request and write it to the file on server

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
       fileName = getFileName(part);           
       InputStream stream=part.getInputStream();

       if(!fileName.equals("NOT_AN_IMAGE")){
       url=fileName;
       //Stores the file in the respective directory
       part.write(uploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);
       }
       else{
           String user_input=Streams.asString(stream);
           i++;
            switch(i){
            case 1:name=user_input;
            break;  
            }      
        }


    }

//Insert String url as path in the database
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    //Storing url of the current file which is uploaded as attribute
    String path=UPLOAD_DIR+"\\"+url;
    //Input text field name
    System.out.println(path);
    System.out.println(name);
    session.setAttribute("field", name);
    session.setAttribute("link",path);
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);


}

//Finding whether it is file or text
private String getFileName(Part part) {

        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        System.out.println("content-disposition header= "+contentDisp);
        String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
        String msg="NOT_AN_IMAGE";
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return msg;
    }

}
```

---

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
<h1 align="center">
<c:out value="${sessionScope.field}"/></h1>

<img src=<c:out value="${sessionScope.link}"/>  width="306" height="208">
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

> When we remove it value will pass,but file is not uploaded.

You can not remove `enctype='multipart/form-data'` , When you make a **POST** request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way.

There are many ways of encoding **POST** request but , When you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.

Use `encType` and In your `Servlet Class`

Instead of Using

`request.getParameter("parameterName");`

use

`MultipartRequest#getParameter("parametername");`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [request.getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) instead of [request.getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)